# Generic way to access private/protected members

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

### Motivation

I and the company is working on building C++ SDK automatically for several platforms, including Windows.
In summary, I have to test somehow if the private member of function pointers' type is correct, since `LoadLibrary` in Windows API only uses function names, ignoring its type.
There is some real-world restriction, so I have to access the private/protected members for testing.

I've searched the internet and found that it could be done using templates, but all examples are not generic, unable to check at compile-time.

So I build my own version that can be done more generically.
The whole source code can be also found at https://github.com/lackhole/Lupin

### Code

Any member can be accessed in explicit template instantiation.
And friend injection allows calling without providing the template class, only by the matching argument(ADL).
So we need an `Accessor` class that holds a pointer to the target class's private member, and the `Accessor` must be able to gotten using appropriate `Tag`.

```
template<typename Tag, typename Class, typename Type, Type ptr_>
struct Accessor {
  using class_type                  = Class;
  using access_type                 = Type;
  using pointer_type                = decltype(ptr_);
  using const_pointer_type          = std::add_const_t<pointer_type>;
  static constexpr pointer_type ptr = ptr_;

  friend auto get_accessor_type_impl(Tag) { return Accessor{}; }
};

template<typename Dummy>
struct Tag {
  friend auto get_accessor_type_impl(Tag);
};
```

We have to keep the friend function inside of the `Accessor` since once we instantiate with a private pointer, we can never re-get its type explicitly because we cannot access a private pointer.
So the above declared the same function in `Tag` and used deduced return type, only to get the `Accessor`'s type.
C++ only allows the friend injection to be remained inside of the class when the class type and the argument type are the same.
This forces us to use C++14 or above, where C++11 cannot deduce the return type with `auto` only.

This can be used like

```
using tag_foo_x = Tag<class foo_x>;
template struct Accessor<tag_foo_x, Foo, decltype(&FOO::x), &Foo::x>;
```

And we have to get `Accessor<tag_foo_x, ...` with `tag_foo_x`, using the friend function above.

```
template<typename Tag>
struct TagTraits {
  using tag_type = Tag;
  using accessor_type       = decltype(get_accessor_type_impl(std::declval<tag_type>()));
  using class_type          = typename accessor_type::class_type;
  using access_type         = typename accessor_type::access_type;
  using pointer_type        = typename accessor_type::pointer_type;
};
```

Now we can get the `Accessor`'s type using `Tag`.

```
using accessor_type = TagTraits<tag_foo_x>::accessor_type;
```

And things are much simple from now.
One has to determine the traits of the pointing type(`ptr_`'s type in `Accessor`), we can use some helper templates.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_function : std::conditional_t<
    std::is_member_function_pointer<std::decay_t<T>>::value ||
    std::is_function<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::value,
  std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

template<typename T>
struct get_pointing_type {
  using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct get_pointing_type<T*> {
  using type = T;
};

template<typename T, typename Class>
struct get_pointing_type<T Class::*> {
  using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using get_pointing_type_t = typename get_pointing_type<T>::type;
```

And for getting the member, one has to vary its return type on the pointing type(variable or a function).

```
/** get non-static member variable */

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<!is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type> &>
get(Target& target) {
  return target.*TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<!is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type> const &>
get(const Target& target) {
  return target.*TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<!is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>>
get(Target&& target) {
  return std::forward<Target>(target).*TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<!is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>>
get(const Target&& target) {
  return std::forward<Target>(target).*TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

/** get non-static member function pointer */

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>
get(Target& target) {
  return TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type const>
get(const Target& target) {
  return TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>
get(Target&& target) {
  return TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag, typename Target>
inline constexpr
std::enable_if_t<is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type const>
get(const Target&& target) {
  return TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

/** get static member (both variable and function) */

template<typename Tag>
std::enable_if_t<!is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type> &>
get() {
  return *TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}

template<typename Tag>
std::enable_if_t<is_function<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>::value,
    typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>
get() {
  return *TagTraits<Tag>::accessor_type::ptr;
}
```

And some sugar function for calling the member function directly.

```
/** call non-static member function */

template<typename Tag, typename Target, typename ...Args>
inline constexpr decltype(auto)
call(Target&& target, Args&&... args) {
  using tag_traits = TagTraits<Tag>;
  using access_type = typename tag_traits::access_type;
  using accessor_type = typename tag_traits::accessor_type;

  static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<access_type>::value,
                "Tag must represent member function, or perhaps the tag represents static member function");
  return (std::forward<Target>(target).*accessor_type::ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


/** call static member function */

template<typename Tag, typename ...Args>
inline constexpr decltype(auto)
call(Args&&... args) {
  using tag_traits = TagTraits<Tag>;
  using access_type = typename tag_traits::access_type;
  using accessor_type = typename tag_traits::accessor_type;

  static_assert(!std::is_member_function_pointer<access_type>::value &&
                std::is_function<std::remove_pointer_t<access_type>>::value,
                "Tag must represent static member function");
  return (accessor_type::ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And last sugar for getting only the type.

```
template<typename Tag>
struct Type {
  using type = get_pointing_type_t<typename TagTraits<Tag>::access_type>;
};

template<typename Tag>
using Type_t = typename Type<Tag>::type;
```

The [macro](https://github.com/lackhole/Lupin/blob/master/include/access/macro.h) is just an alias for creating a tag and explicit template instantiation.
The usage is like below

```
#include "access/access.h"

struct hidden {
 private:
  int x = 10;
  std::string str = "hello";
  int func() const &{ return x; }
  int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

  static int sta() { return y; }
  static int y;

};
int hidden::y = 12345;

ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_x, hidden, x);
ACCESS_CREATE_UNIQUE_TAG(hidden, x);
ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_str, hidden, str);

ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_func, hidden, func);
ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_sum, hidden, sum);
ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_sta, hidden, sta);
ACCESS_CREATE_TAG(tag_hidden_y, hidden, y);

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  hidden h;

  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_x>(h) << std::endl;
  std::cout << access::get<ACCESS_GET_UNIQUE_TAG(hidden, x)>(h) << std::endl;

  access::get<tag_hidden_x>(h) = 100;
  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_x>(h) << std::endl;
  access::get<ACCESS_GET_UNIQUE_TAG(hidden, x)>(h) = 200;
  std::cout << access::get<ACCESS_GET_UNIQUE_TAG(hidden, x)>(h) << std::endl;

  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_y>() << std::endl;
  access::get<tag_hidden_y>() = -123;
  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_y>() << std::endl;

  access::call<tag_hidden_func>(h);
  (h.*access::get<tag_hidden_func>(h))();

  access::call<tag_hidden_sum>(h, 1, 2);

  access::get<tag_hidden_sta>()();
  access::call<tag_hidden_sta>();

  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_str>(h) << std::endl;
  access::get<tag_hidden_str>(std::move(h));
  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_str>(h) << std::endl;

  const hidden h2;
  access::get<tag_hidden_x>(h2);

  access::call<tag_hidden_func>(h2);
  (h.*access::get<tag_hidden_func>(h2))();

  std::cout << access::get<tag_hidden_sta>()() << std::endl;
  std::cout << access::call<tag_hidden_sta>() << std::endl;

  static_assert(std::is_same<access::Type_t<tag_hidden_x>, int>::value, "");
  static_assert(std::is_same<access::Type_t<tag_hidden_y>, int>::value, "");

  // Note that the below two type is different. Choose your own way.
  static_assert(std::is_same<access::Type_t<tag_hidden_func>, int () const&>::value, "");                                           // function type
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(access::get<tag_hidden_func>(std::declval<hidden>())), int (hidden::*)() const&>::value, ""); // function pointer type

  
  // Note that these two are different too
  static_assert(std::is_same<access::Type_t<tag_hidden_sta>, int()>::value, "");              // function type
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(access::get<tag_hidden_sta>()), int(*)()>::value, "");  // function pointer type

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your feedbacks!
Is there any more portable or better way to improve this?
Like support C++11 using different friend injection tricks, or some value/template features that I missed.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We can answer questions like `And I can't understand why gcc<10 cannot compile the 4 overloads of call`. All we do on this site is review the existing code and provide suggestions on how to improve that working code. We are also unable to review code that contains `...` instead of code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thanks for pointing it out. I Used `...` because the content is almost the same, only differs in parameter type(&, const &, &&, const &&`). So I thought it will drop the readability since it's quite a lot of code. I'll update the content to show all codes

Comment: @김선달, one reason it's good to show nearly-repeated code is that you might get suggestions on how to better arrange it to reduce the duplication.

Comment: I think I'm missing something... your checking code relies on the class definitions in a header file.  This does not actually check that the `LoadLibrary` symbol actually matches the definition in that header; it could be an old version or a different piece of code that happens to have the same name.

Comment: @JDługosz My situation was: internal source code must be hidden, so it is build to a DLL file with some `extern "C"` code. But we must make it portable, so the source code of the wrapper(that loads the C function) is also provided. The wrapper links the DLL file's function to the corresponding function pointer, which is held as private. DLL + wrapper is a single SDK, so the wrapper must not change just for testing. The automated test code can access both `extern "C"` header files and the `wrapper.h`, while the wrapper doesn't.

Comment: @JDługosz I know that the test can be done somehow instead of accessing the private fields, but I thought this is more intuitive(represent intent). My situation was just motivation for writing this library. The point is that this is a generic, standard way to access private fields.

Comment: I still don't see how it tests that the type of pointer is correct... it simply doesn't know what the type is in the `extern "C"` function that it loaded from the library.

Comment: `LoadLibrary` doesn't check types. `wrapper.h` doesn't include `extern "C"` file. This is my problem here. So the test code includes both `extern "C"` header files and `wrapper.h`. So it knows both types, making it able to check if they're the same.